# ListBox working on WPF but not on Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml

I've got a style:

```
<Style x:Key="StarPathStyle" TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="#FF000080"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeStartLineCap" Value="Round"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeEndLineCap" Value="Round"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeLineJoin" Value="Round"/>
            <Setter Property="StrokeMiterLimit" Value="1"/>     
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="F1 M 145.637,174.227L 127.619,110.39L 180.809,70.7577L 114.528,68.1664L 93.2725,5.33333L 70.3262,67.569L 4,68.3681L 56.0988,109.423L 36.3629,172.75L 91.508,135.888L 145.637,174.227 Z"/>
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFFFFF00">
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And a ListBox that shows a few items:

```
<ListBox Background="LightGray" Margin="8,171.5,8,8">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

            <Button Content="Hello" />
            <Path Style="{StaticResource StarPathStyle}" />
            <Ellipse Width="10" Height="20" Fill="Blue" />
            <Ellipse Width="20" Height="10" Fill="Blue" />
            <Path Style="{StaticResource StarPathStyle}" />
        </ListBox>
```

**Question: Why does it work on WPF but not on Silverlight 3.0?**

On Silveright it gives "***ArgumentException***" stating that "*Value does not fall within the expected range.*"

.pom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure, but I found by moving the "Data" from the styling resource and into the XAML file, it works:

```
<Path Style="{StaticResource StarPathStyle}"
Data="F1 M 145.637,174.227L 127.619,110.39L 180.809,70.7577L 114.528,68.1664L 93.2725,5.33333L 70.3262,67.569L 4,68.3681L 56.0988,109.423L 36.3629,172.75L 91.508,135.888L 145.637,174.227 Z" />
```